# How to go for next page and previous page in react js and axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx

I am new to react js. I am trying to achieve the pagination using API response. I want re-render the data whenever I click on the next page, previous page, last_page URL. Help me to achieve the simple pagination using re-render concept.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from '../axios';

function Transaction() {
 const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

 const [fetchUrl, setFetchUrl] = useState('default-url');

 useEffect(() => {
     console.log(fetchUrl);
     async function fetchData() {
        const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
        setTransactions(request?.data?.payload);

        return request;
    }
    fetchData();
 }, [setFetchUrl]);
 return (
    <div className="wraper">
    <h2>Transactions</h2>
    <div className="pagination">

    {/* <Pagination count={transactions?.last_page_url} />    */}
    <button onClick={ () => setFetchUrl(transactions?.last_page_url) }>Previos Page- 
   {(transactions?.current_page)-1}</button>
        <p>Current Page {transactions?.current_page}</p>
        
        <button onClick={ () => setFetchUrl(transactions?.next_page_url) }>Next Page- 
   {(transactions?.current_page)+1}</button>
        <button onClick={ () => setFetchUrl(transactions?.next_page_url) }>Last Page- 
 {(transactions?.last_page)}</button>
    </div>    
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>datetime</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {transactions?.data?.map((transaction) => (
          <tr key={transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}>
            <td>{transaction.ID_PAYMENTS}</td>
            <td>{transaction.TransQuantity}</td>
            <td>{transaction.CardSystem}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  )
}
export default Transaction;
```

Response json file

```
 {
      "success": "true",
      "payload": {
      "current_page": 1,
      "data": [
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485315",
            "TransQuantity": "167.64999399999999",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "9981.8799",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 15:03:55.230",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "99000.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-29240792.0000",
            "Mileage": "398678",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "455",
            "vehicle_desc": "TANKER ON CONTRACT",
            "LicensePlate": "MP14HC0173",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 15:03:55.237",
            "ID_CARDS": "1064",
            "Number": "7131",
            "PAN": "9100339200027713129",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "14",
            "terminal_desc": "AFT-FS-INDORE",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "65",
            "contracts_desc": "CSPL",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-07-14 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485314",
            "TransQuantity": "60.0",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "68.8200",
            "TransAmount": "1970.4000",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 15:00:29.357",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "99000.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-29240732.0000",
            "Mileage": "1",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1289",
            "vehicle_desc": "ALL BUSES",
            "LicensePlate": "SCPL INDORE",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 15:00:29.363",
            "ID_CARDS": "2003",
            "Number": "26355",
            "PAN": "000000000011226355=",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "8",
            "terminal_desc": "SANATHAL FS",
            "StationCode": "1",
            "StationName": "SANATHAL",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "65",
            "contracts_desc": "CSPL",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-07-14 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485313",
            "TransQuantity": "145.44000199999999",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "8659.5000",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 14:51:46.110",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32832538.0000",
            "Mileage": "228554",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1143",
            "vehicle_desc": "DELUXE BUS(HPV)",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA9342",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 14:51:46.120",
            "ID_CARDS": "800",
            "Number": "6761",
            "PAN": "9100339200027676128",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485312",
            "TransQuantity": "161.39999399999999",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "9609.7598",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 14:51:46.080",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32832376.0000",
            "Mileage": "279486",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1105",
            "vehicle_desc": "TATA NON AC",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA9346",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 14:51:46.083",
            "ID_CARDS": "1940",
            "Number": "7367",
            "PAN": "9100339200027736724",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485311",
            "TransQuantity": "95.410004000000001",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "5680.7100",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 14:43:27.843",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32832280.0000",
            "Mileage": "407843",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1024",
            "vehicle_desc": "VOLVO",
            "LicensePlate": "MP04PA7290",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 14:43:27.863",
            "ID_CARDS": "1719",
            "Number": "7273",
            "PAN": "9100339200027727327",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "20",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE - 5652",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485310",
            "TransQuantity": "103.870003",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "68.8200",
            "TransAmount": "3411.0901",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 14:30:31.497",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "99000.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-29240628.0000",
            "Mileage": "155496",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "1289",
            "vehicle_desc": "ALL BUSES",
            "LicensePlate": "SCPL INDORE",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 15:00:29.363",
            "ID_CARDS": "2003",
            "Number": "26355",
            "PAN": "000000000011226355=",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "8",
            "terminal_desc": "SANATHAL FS",
            "StationCode": "1",
            "StationName": "SANATHAL",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "65",
            "contracts_desc": "CSPL",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-07-14 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485309",
            "TransQuantity": "191.729996",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "11415.5996",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 14:21:47.687",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32832088.0000",
            "Mileage": "268681",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "753",
            "vehicle_desc": "TATA",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA8924",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 14:21:47.697",
            "ID_CARDS": "1565",
            "Number": "6321",
            "PAN": "9100339200027632121",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "19",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -3209",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485308",
            "TransQuantity": "190.35000600000001",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "11333.4404",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 14:04:26.503",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32831898.0000",
            "Mileage": "5652",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "737",
            "vehicle_desc": "MB INDORE",
            "LicensePlate": "MB 5652",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 14:04:26.510",
            "ID_CARDS": "749",
            "Number": "6705",
            "PAN": "9100339200027670527",
            "Cardholder": "C 2  TO MB 5652",
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "16",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE -0928",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485307",
            "TransQuantity": "198.070007",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "59.5400",
            "TransAmount": "11793.0898",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 13:58:44.730",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32831700.0000",
            "Mileage": "114243",
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": "831",
            "vehicle_desc": "LPO1618/AC",
            "LicensePlate": "MP09FA8950",
            "ActMilageType": "K",
            "ActMilageDate": "2021-03-26 13:58:44.737",
            "ID_CARDS": "1758",
            "Number": "6248",
            "PAN": "9100339200027624821",
            "Cardholder": null,
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "20",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE - 5652",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
        },
        {
            "ID_PAYMENTS": "485306",
            "TransQuantity": "1284.459961",
            "TransSinglePriceInclSold": "65.8600",
            "TransAmount": "84594.5391",
            "TransArticleID": "3",
            "TransArticleDescription": "Diesel",
            "TransPollDateTime": "2021-03-26 13:35:23.070",
            "CardSystem": "(C) Vehicle Card (1 card)",
            "CardLimit": "990.0000",
            "CardOnHand": "-32830416.0000",
            "Mileage": null,
            "TransWasExported": "N",
            "ID_CUSTOMERS": "10",
            "Company": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Firstname": null,
            "Lastname": "CHARTERED SPEED LTD",
            "Street": "SARKHEJ BAVLA HIGHWAY",
            "City": "AHMEDABAD, GUJARAT",
            "ZipCode": "382210",
            "ID_VEHICLES": null,
            "vehicle_desc": null,
            "LicensePlate": null,
            "ActMilageType": null,
            "ActMilageDate": null,
            "ID_CARDS": "1997",
            "Number": "2275",
            "PAN": "000000000011227564=",
            "Cardholder": "sand to indore",
            "IsMasterCard": "N",
            "ID_TERMINALS": "13",
            "terminal_desc": "INDORE-8587",
            "StationCode": "3",
            "StationName": "INDORE",
            "Active": "Y",
            "ID_CONTRACTS": "70",
            "contracts_desc": "INDORE ",
            "DateValidFrom": "2018-08-05 00:00:00.000",
            "DateValidTo": "2049-12-31 00:00:00.000"
          }
         ],
         "first_page_url": "default-url?page=1",
         "from": 1,
         "last_page": 7747,
         "last_page_url": "default-url?page=7747",
         "next_page_url": "default-url?page=2",
         "path": "default-url",
         "per_page": 10,
         "prev_page_url": null,
         "to": 10,
         "total": 77462
       }
     }
```

Comment: where did you stick in your code?

Comment: @Rajesha RL I think you almost achieve it. Just replace setFetchUrl in your dependencies array in your useEffect with fetchUrl. It should work.